# MFP Analytics 7.1 console not showing MFP 7.1 server logs (on Server GUI Tab)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, websphere-liberty

I have install properly my MFP 7.1 server and my MFP 7.1 analytics server.  They are running on separate machine.  I can see that the server logs are being sent to my MFP analytics server, however I cannot see anything on the "Server" tab".

attached are screen shot of 1) MFP analytics server  "Adminstration" tab and 2) MFP analytics server "Sever" tab.

[admin tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YFgi.gif)

[server tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLHJi.gif)

Here is my analytics server.xml (FYI, both my MFP servers are installed on top of IBM Liberty)

```html
<server description="simple server">
<application location="analytics.ear"
    name="analytics-ear"
    type="ear">
  <application-bnd>
    <security-role name="worklightadmin">
       <user name="wlanalytic"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
       <user name="deployer"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
       <user name="monitor"/>
    </security-role>
    <security-role name="worklightoperator">
       <user name="operator"/>
    </security-role>
   </application-bnd>
</application>


<basicRegistry id="worklight" realm="worklightRealm">
  <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
  <user name="monitor" password="demo"/>
  <user name="deployer" password="demo"/>
  <user name="operator" password="demo"/>
  <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
  <user name="wlanalytic" password="wl_report" />
</basicRegistry>


    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
   <jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/shards" value="6" />
   <jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/replicas_per_shard" value="1" />

   <jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/http.enabled" value="false" />


    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9082"
                  httpsPort="9445"
                  accessLoggingRef="accessLogging"/>

     <httpAccessLogging id="accessLogging"
                logFormat='%h %u %{t}W "%r" %s %b' />


     <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig"
         keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
         trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
         clientAuthenticationSupported="true" />



    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="changeit"
              location="/default.jks" />

    <keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" password="changeit"
              location="/TrustCA.jks" />



</server>
```

Can some IBM MFP expert provide some insight.  Thanks

Comment: How are you seeing server logs being sent to analytics? Can we see?

Comment: Your filter is set to June 17th, could this be the issue? Were you collecting logs on those days? Can you change it to the past 30 or 90 days and see if you get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the JNDI property:

`wl.analytics.logs.forward` set to true in your server.xml. You should have:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/wl.analytics.logs.forward" value="true" />
```

You also need to be collecting logs specific to worklight. Analytics is only going to forward server logs from `com.ibm.worklight.*`

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me where this is documented.  I can only find parameters from this url: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_properties.html

Comment: So I am a bit confused, isn't this "wl.analytics.logs.forward" JNDI property for the MFP server?  Not the Analytics server.  Recall, I have these instances on separate machines.

Comment: hi @O.W. it is indeed on your MFP server. Do you have it in your server.xml?